# How do I programmatically remove an existing rule that was defined in XML?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, layoutparams

I have a linear layout that is contained inside a relative layout. 
It is set in the XML file to be to the right of another linear layout (this works fine).
In some cases I want to change the relative position of the layout during the onCreate of the activity so I need to modify the "to the right of" param to relate to another layout.
I tryed this:

```
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams;

    layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) linearLayoutToMove
            .getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,
            R.id.new_ref_LinearLayout);
```

But it does not work :o(

Any clues ?

Answer (score 155, accepted):

You can't remove a rule because all rules are always stored in a fixed-size java array. But you can set a rule to `0`. For example

```
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, 0);
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.new_ref_LinearLayout);
```

**EDIT** (thanks to [Roger Rapid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1163508)):

As of API level 17, the class `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` has the following method:

```
public void removeRule(int verb)
```

So you can remove a rule using the following line of code:

```
layoutParams.removeRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF);
```

And you will get exactly the same result as when 'adding' a zero-rule as:

```
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, 0);
```

Comment: As of API level 17, the class RelativeLayout.LayoutParams has the following method: public void removeRule (int verb)

Comment: What do I do for apps before api level 17? :o

Comment: @marienke Setting a rule to `0` is similar to removing the rule.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to call:

`relativeLayout.updateViewLayout(linearLayoutToMove, layoutParams);`

after changing the LayoutParams.

In reply to the edit, you can create new LayoutParameters using:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
```

and then add your new rules.  Then, update the layout parameters using the previously mentioned updateViewLayout() method.

Answer (score 0):

add the following code to your existing code

`linearLayoutToMove.setLayoutParams(layoutParams)`

I think this should do the job. In case if the above line dont work, try to call `linearLayoutToMove.invalidate()` after the above line.

Comment: Since I am in onCreate, I do not need to call invalidate().