# How can I abolish addRule-Rules?

Tags: android

I created a field of buttons in my XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout...>
<Button  
    android:id="@+id/button_1"
    ...
    />
<Button  
    android:id="@+id/button_2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_1"  
...
/>
...
</RelativeLayout>enter code here
```

Now I want to abolish the XML rule "toRightOf" programmaticaly.
I know how to set rules:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = null;
params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, topIcon.getId());
button_2.setLayoutParams(params);
```

But I want to DELETE rules I had set in XML file.
How can this be done?

The background of my question: I used an XML file to easily
create field of buttons.
But later I want to drag and drop buttons.
For that I have to delete rules like "toRightOf".
Otherwise instead of one button a lot of buttons
move if I only want to move one button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107740/how-to-modify-a-relative-layout-rule-programaticaly), it cannot be removed but instead you set the value to 0:

```
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, 0);
```

Comment: As of API level 17, the class RelativeLayout.LayoutParams has the following method: public void removeRule (int verb)