# How to set layout_alignParentRight="false" programmatically?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, android-layoutparams

How to set `android:layout_alignParentRight="false"` programmatically? I can set it to `true` by this code but I want to set it to `false` programmatically:

```
RelativeLayout.Layoutparams params =
(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)myView.getLayoutParams();
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
button.setLayoutParams(params);
```

There is a method [removeRule(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#removeRule%28int%29) but it's added in (API level 17). I want to use something like this in API level 7 or 8.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107740/how-to-modify-a-relative-layout-rule-programaticaly

Comment: thanks works with this: `addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT,0)`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

this code will set it false:

```
addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT,0)
```