# Removing/Adding constraint programmatically in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, android-layoutparams

I want to remove and add constraint programmatically based on some condition. Here are the screenshots:

[image: The button "create ad" has a top constraint]

and I want to remove it like this but in code:

[image: here is button with removed constraint on top]

so the same effect in want to achieve programmatically

and here is the code that I tried:

```
    if (advertisements.size() > 0) { //my own condition
        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) btnCreateAd.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.topToBottom = R.id.imvEmpty; //the imageview that is in center of the view
        btnCreateAd.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        txvMyAdEmptyText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        imvEmpty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        adapter.setList(advertisements);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } else {
        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) btnCreateAd.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.topToBottom = -1; //here i am trying to remove top constraint but it doesn't work
        btnCreateAd.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        txvMyAdEmptyText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        imvEmpty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        adapter.setList(new ArrayList<Advertisement>());
    }
    mConstraintView.invalidate(); //this is my constraint view
```

**EDIT**

I have [tried using](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintSet.html) `ConstraintSet` also, but the result was even different somehow my RecyclerView (which is set to boundaries of parent view) was disappearing

```
 ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
    set.clone(parentView);

    if (advertisements.size() > 0) {

        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        txvMyAdEmptyText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        imvEmpty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        adapter.setList(advertisements);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    } else {

        set.connect(btnCreateAd.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, imvEmpty.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 0);

        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        txvMyAdEmptyText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        imvEmpty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        adapter.setList(new ArrayList<Advertisement>());
    }
    set.connect(btnCreateAd.getId(), ConstraintSet.END, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.END, 0);
    set.connect(btnCreateAd.getId(), ConstraintSet.START, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.START, 0);
    set.connect(btnCreateAd.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 0);

    set.applyTo(parentView);
```

Comment: see if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107740/how-do-i-programmatically-remove-an-existing-rule-that-was-defined-in-xml

Comment: @ValdioVeliu sorry, but that is for RelativeLayout params, i need from constraintLayoutParams.

Comment: @Chisko i have tried also with ConstraintSet but it doesn't work for this case, and moreover somehow it is breaking my other constraints of the views. By the way all views are already created in layout (i mean I don't create a view dynamically).

Answer (score 184, accepted):

I have not worked through your code, but the following illustrates how to break and make the constraint using `ConstraintSet`.

```java
ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
ConstraintLayout layout;

layout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
set.clone(layout);
// The following breaks the connection.
set.clear(R.id.bottomText, ConstraintSet.TOP);
// Comment out line above and uncomment line below to make the connection.
// set.connect(R.id.bottomText, ConstraintSet.TOP, R.id.imageView, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 0);
set.applyTo(layout);
```

Comment: @DominikusK.Oops, thanks for calling me out! If your interested in animating these transitions, this is a helpful [post](https://robinhood.engineering/beautiful-animations-using-android-constraintlayout-eee5b72ecae3)

Comment: Has anyone noticed any problem with Api 21 or 22 with ConstraintLayout 1.1.1 when changing the constraints?

Seems to be a bit unreliable though works perfectly on api 28

Comment: Yes @Bakhshi, I've noticed the same thing. Have you resolved it? If yes, how? I'm using version 1.1.3

Comment: `set.clone(layout);` this line was very important, since my layout started to disappear after I apply without this line.

Answer (score 23):

There is an easier way to do it now if you're using viewBinding/dataBinding with Kotlin.

There is an extension function called updateLayoutParams from `import androidx.core.view.updateLayoutParams` and use it like below

```
    binding.yourView.updateLayoutParams<ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams> {
                        this.startToEnd = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.UNSET
                      this.startToStart = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.PARENT_ID
                    }
```

Comment: This is so far the best answer for me!! `ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.UNSET`. It is the most sophisticated and latest update for update layout params programmatically.

Answer (score 21):

Another way of doing this is with **ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.UNSET**. This way is not using `ConstraintSet.clear`.

Assuming we want to remove the bottom constraint of our constraintLayout itself but can be any view:

```
val containerParams = cl_container.layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
containerParams.bottomToBottom = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.UNSET
cl_container.layoutParams = containerParams
```

Comment: Can you provide a java version of this code please??

Comment: Kotlin and Java is interchangeable. Look for an option to change it in the ide or online

Answer (score 4):

Here is the Java version of the answer from [j2emanue](https://stackoverflow.com/users/835883/j2emanue) using [`ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams), which works without specifying the id of the element that the layout is contrained to:

```
final ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.constraintLayout);
final ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) constraintLayout.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.bottomToBottom = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.UNSET;
constraintLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```