# How to clear constraints of Widgets (e.g ImageView) inside ConstraintLayout programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-xml, android-constraintlayout

I searched everywhere, How to clear constraints of Widgets inside ConstraintLayout, the one result that I found is at stack OverFlow in this link : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44685816/removing-adding-constraint-programmatically-in-constraintlayout)

But the answer of this question, doesn't work in my case, however, my question is how could i clear constraint of the widget (E.g ImageView) inside ConstraintLayout programmatically. here's a picture that illustrates what am asking for,thank's. 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your xml constraints of your view to find out which constraint to clear, it happened to me to clear LEFT while it was constrained with START.

Comment: Thanks, it's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

create clone of current set and then apply new constraints to it then apply it to view

```
ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout);
constraintSet.connect(R.id.imageView,ConstraintSet.RIGHT,R.id.check_answer1,ConstraintSet.RIGHT,0);
constraintSet.connect(R.id.imageView,ConstraintSet.TOP,R.id.check_answer1,ConstraintSet.TOP,0);
constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout);
```

Comment: Thanks, but  it's Doesn't work with RIGHT and LEFT, that's work with START and END !!